# SQL multiple properties depending on other attributes

Tags: sql, database-design

I have the following issue:

I am planning a database with trains. Each train has carriages which divides into compartment and non-compartment. Both of these types has three classes: 1,2,3, and all of them has different amount of places in compartment or in a row.

I could create the following table:

```
| type | class | seats in a row  | rows | seats in a compartment  | compartments |

| non-c| 1     | 3               | 18   | NULL                    | NULL         |
| non-c| 2     | 4               | 22   | NULL                    | NULL         |
| non-c| 3     | 5               | 25   | NULL                    | NULL         |
| comp | 1     | NULL            | NULL | 6                       | 9            |
| comp | 2     | NULL            | NULL | 8                       | 10           |
| comp | 3     | NULL            | NULL | 10                      | 11           |
```

That is, I would set NULL when a property is not connected with a particular type (example number of places in a compartment for a non-compartment car), but in my opinion it is not good looking solution. Do you have any other ideas? Maybe two tables: non-compartment attributes and compartment attributes? However I think that better solution exists.

Comment: Like you said, break your design into tables that correspond to logical entities ([normalization](http://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php)), that way you will have more scope to accommodate change and less redundant data.

Answer (score 0):

Like you said, break your design into tables that correspond to logical entities (normalization), that way you will have more scope to accommodate change and less redundant info.

**Proposed design**

Tables

`Tbl_train(Id, other_train_info)` -Stores only tran info

`Tbl_Carriage(Id, trainid, carriagetypeid, other_carriage_info)` - stores carriage info related to a train

`Tbl_carriagetype_master(Id, type_desc, class, .. Etc)` - stores all the static compartmental info